# How mysql AUTO_INCREMENT works?

Tags: mysql

In [mysql AUTO_INCREMENT doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), I didn't find the detail explanation about how it pick new id on insert,

Is it cache a "max number" key, or find the smallest ID which is not in use? any reference to the source code?

EDIT:

I had test it, looks like it will not reuse deleted item's ID, But I'm not sure. I want use id as a timestamp for ordering, so I must 100% certain it is so, that means this logic explanation should has a trusted reference, either in source code or in mysql doc..

Comment: From your own link: *You can retrieve the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value with the LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function or the mysql_insert_id() C API function.*

Comment: Yes, I can get last insert ID, what I want to know, is how mysql-server picks this id.

Comment: Alvaro: That works when you insert a new record (via a C, PHP etc. application) and want to know what ID was assigned to this row that you just inserted.

Comment: No it doesn't take the smallest unoccupied integer, It takes the max+1 from the table>
It does this either by using its cache, or a sequence number

Comment: Dammit, I misread "how it pick" for "how to pick"...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'i want to use id as timestamp'. if you want a timestamp, create a DATETIME column with a a default value of `NOW()`

Comment: MySQL uses a per-table counter. Every time a request for the id occurs, MySQL returns the current value and increments the number. There are multiple valid reasons why MySQL won't "reuse" the numbers that are currently "free", so I'll avoid mentioning them.

Answer (score 1):

It will NOT pick the smallest number not in use. It will always increment one to the last ID it had assigned. This will be a constant time operation. (As opposed to picking the smallest number not in use which would be linear time*).

For example, if you insert 10 rows, then delete the 5th row. The next inserted row will get an ID of 11, and NOT 5.

*This operation can quite easily be optimized to be constant time as well (at the time of insertion) by accepting a penalty at the time of deletion. However, that is not what MySQL does.*

Comment: I had test it, and looks like so, But I'm not sure. I want to use id as a timestamp, so I must 100% certain it is so, that means this logic should has a solid place explanation, either in source code or in mysql doc..

Comment: It's a terrible idea to use timestamps as IDs, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the way `auto_increment` works.

- The value will be incremented for each new row
- The value is unique, duplicates are not possible
- If a row is deleted, the `auto_increment` column of that row will not be re-assigned.
- The `auto_increment` value of the last inserted row can be accessed using the mySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but it must be called right after the insert query, in the same database connection.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html